# Separating Columns into Variables

Tags: r

I'm looking to take 79 columns and make a unique variable for each column.
I can manually create the variables by subsetting:

```
    v1 <- x[1]
    v2 <- x[2]
    etc.
```

I was wondering if/know there's a much faster way to do it. I'm just not really sure how.
Right now I have:

```
    test <- matrix(rep(1,79), nrow = 1, ncol = 79)
    c2v <- function(test){
        for (i in c(1:79){
          v[i] <- test[i]
        }
        return(v[i])
    }
    c2v(test)
```

Thanks as always for the help!

Jon

Comment: This question needs some serious work. Aside from the typos that make the code you've written nonsensical, you're going to need to provide a more complete explanation of what you're trying to accomplish and why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about something like:

```
test <- matrix(rep(1,79), nrow = 1, ncol = 79)

for (i in 1:ncol(test)) {
   temp <- (paste(c("v",i), collapse=""))
   assign(temp,test[i])
}
```

I'm sure it could be reconfigured to get rid of the loop, but this should work.

**Future me editing my past mistakes:**

Something like the following may be a more appropriate non-loop solution.

```
list2env(as.data.frame(test),envir=.GlobalEnv)
```

It is probably still better practice to work with a `data.frame` or `list` than breaking up to individual vectors.

Comment: vectorize vectorize vectorize. Loops in R are very inefficient.

Comment: @Maiasaura - i'm aware of that, but I can't for the life of me think of how to remove the loop at this stage. I'm working on it.

Comment: Worrying about avoiding `for` loops can, like anything else, be overdone. It's fun to do as an exercise, but in this case, I doubt it's worth stressing out about looping over only 79 columns.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

```
    library(reshape)
    new_data= melt(data, id.vars=1)
    # Assuming the first column is the ID variable. 
    #If you have more than one, you can specify a range like 1:4
```